# Multitrack Recording in PsychoPy

Tags: python, audio, sox, psychopy

Is it possible to record from a mic while playback of an audio file continues?

If so, can I use a headphone splitter to record exactly what the listener hears to the same track?

Ideally, I would like a stereo audio file wherein one track is the original audio file, and the second track is what the mic simultaneously recorded.

Context:

In my experiment, participants will listen to audio clips, then attempt to synchronize with them using a musical instrument, while the audio clip continues to play.

It's really important I'm able to analyze how closely they are able to reproduce/temporally coordinate with the stimulus. I'm not too concerned with quality, as long as I can accurately compare event onsets.

Comment: The first thing I would check is if the audio card is capable of such thing (full-duplex recording).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have access to a fully equipped, professional audio recording studio at my school. Not sure if that's what you mean?

Comment: I meant to check if you can do recording and playback at the same time with the same audio card.

Comment: Hi Milo, thanks again. I'm not sure, but the way I was planning to achieve this was to use a headphone splitter, so that whatever the participant is getting in his or her actual earpiece is what is being recorded at the same time as their response. I hope that makes sense!